# HTTP+SSL via curl and Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, ssl, curl

I have a self-signed sertificate, and web-site based on apache 2.x, with this certificate.
Just want to access this site from my software using via SSL.

doing following:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mysite.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "n.crt");
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "D:\\");
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L) ;
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT); 

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

but each time I get:

```
* About to connect() to mysite.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 1.1.1.1... * connected
* Connected to mysite.com (1.1.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: n.crt
  CApath: D:\

* Closing connection #0
* Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Could you please advice, what i'm doing wrong?

PS:

- Win7 x64
- MSVC++ 2010
- curl 7.19.3 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.19.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8j Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps

Answer (score 0):

Find the location of n.crt. When an executable runs, all file checks are relative to its path. So either put the n.crt in your executable's folder, or put the absolute path of the file while setting CURLOPT_CAINFO. Otherwise use relative path of the cert info file.